# Change orders status by order number in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I would like to know if there is a way that i can change status of a bunch of orders with a list of order numbers, exemple :
Change status of this orders from "In progess" to "Completed"

638
637
636
635
634

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through ids and use [wp_update_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) to update stautus.
Here's a [list](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_statuses#2) of wc order statuses.

```
$order_ids = [ 638, 637, 636, 635, 634 ];

foreach( $order_ids as $id ) {
   wp_update_post([
       'ID'          => $id,
       'post_status' => 'wc-completed'
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its exactly what i wanted to do.